# R - Soundecology MultipleSounds package not reading directory

Tags: r

My using Soundecology R package. The funtion MultipleSounds is giving me trouble when reading the directory, telling me that it doesnt find the directory or it doesnt have access to it. However, it does.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please show the code you are using and the evidence you are using to prove the directory exists and it has access to it? Without any sort of details it's very hard to guess what exactly is happening.

Comment: Hello! thanks for your answer, how do i prove that it has access to it?